# Problems using lat/long data for a layout in ggraph

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph

I am trying to figure how to use a lat/long layout in `ggraph` but can't seem to work my way through the syntax. Consider this reprex with some data modified from the `iris` dataset:

```
data <- structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.4, 4.6, 
5, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 
3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4), Lon = c(-122.683, -122.688, 
-122.686, -122.683, -122.678, -122.675, -122.674, -122.673, -122.676, 
-122.674, -122.677, -122.68), Lat = c(45.523, 45.52, 45.514, 
45.515, 45.513, 45.514, 45.517, 45.519, 45.519, 45.522, 45.524, 
45.521)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
"Lon", "Lat"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))

library(ggplot2)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
```

A simple plot of the positions of the coordinates looks like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat)) +
  geom_point(size = 6)
```

[image]

`layout` accepts a matrix so I'll extract here the coordinates and turn it into a matrix:

```
spatial_layout <- layout.norm(as.matrix(data[,c(3,4)]))
```

and then turn `data` into a igraph object:

```
igraph_data <- graph_from_data_frame(data)
```

If I plot with the basic `plot.igraph` the layout is as expected; the spatial coordinates of each point:

```
plot.igraph(igraph_data, layout = spatial_layout)
```

[image]

Now here is where I run into problems. I would rather use `ggraph` to take advantage of the power of `ggplot2`. However I am not sure how to get it to accept a spatial layout. This doesn't work:

```
ggraph(igraph_data, spatial_layout) +
  geom_edge_link() +
  geom_node_point(color = "black", size = 9, pch = 1) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name))
```

> Error in create_layout.igraph(graph, layout, ...) : Unknown layout

Nor does trying to create a custom layout:

```
create_layout(data, layout = "spatial_layout")
```

> Error in create_layout.default(data, layout = "spatial_layout") :
>   No layout function defined for objects of class data.frame

Manually adding the lat/long data to the igraph object doesn't seem to do the trick either:

```
igraph_data$layout=cbind(E(igraph_data)$Lon,E(igraph_data)$Lat)
ggraph(igraph_data) +
  geom_edge_link() +
  geom_node_point(color = "black", size = 9, pch = 1) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name))
```

> Using `nicely` as default layout Error in data.frame(..., check.names
>   = FALSE) :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 12, 17

So ultimately my question is how do I add spatial data to a `ggraph` layout? Obviously I am missing something here but I can't seem to figure out the right approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can make the equivalent manual layout with `ggraph::create_layout`. But first, we need to make the number of spatial coordinates match the number of vertexes in the graph we are passing. Looks like `plot.igraph` was recycling your original layout silently.

```
# must have columns named x and y
data2 <-  data.frame(x = rep(spatial_layout[,1], length.out = 17),
                     y = rep(spatial_layout[,2], length.out = 17))
```

Then use the help page for `?layout_igraph_manual` as a guide for subsequent argument names.

```
manual_layout <- create_layout(graph = igraph_data,
              layout = "manual", node.positions = data2)
```

Note: I raise the warning `Error: 'layout_igraph_manual' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggraph'` when I call the function directly.

Then we can plug it into the original:

```
ggraph(manual_layout) + 
    geom_edge_link() +
    geom_node_point(color = "black", size = 9, pch = 1) +
    geom_node_text(aes(label = name))
```

[image]

The axis limits are not the same by default, but that's a small `+ xlim(-2.5,2.5)#ish` tweak.

Comment: Thank you! Can you see anyway that you can apply a projection to this? I turned it into an `sf` object but ggraph wouldn't plot it.

Comment: not off the top of my head, it might be easier to just build polygons or lines via a spatial plotting package instead of  `ggraph`

Comment: Yep this is sort of the approach I took. Process the node coordinates before the layout step using the same projection as the polygon then plot the polygon using geom_polygon. Worked well.

Comment: this approach can be used to convert any non-ggraph layout to a ggraph layout, so very useful (I used it to get the layout_as_star(), which gives more control over the star-layout than the one in ggraph, into gggraph.)